# texture painting color with wrong color

Tags: texturing

[image]
I am trying to texture paint this pawn but for some reason it is not working correctly. Here i am trying to paint this orange but blender is painting it green. when i try to paint it blue blender paints in low intensity red.  I try changing materials, light, objects, normal no change.

Answer (score 1):

Your blend type is set to mix. Change it to add.

[image]